# how get Shared Deep Link value in android

Tags: android, firebase

HI i am using firebase dynamic link for deeplink in our app .

during share post i am sharing below link:
https://xyz.page.link/navigator?id=6502ae981c4900015116c4fa

and its redirect to our app but when i try to get id value using below code

```
 val uri = intent.data

private fun getDynamicLinkFromFireBase() {
        Firebase.dynamicLinks
            .getDynamicLink(intent)
            .addOnSuccessListener(this) { pendingDynamicLinkData: PendingDynamicLinkData? ->
                // Get deep link from result (may be null if no link is found)
                var deepLink: Uri? = null
                if (pendingDynamicLinkData != null) {
                    deepLink = pendingDynamicLinkData.link
                    Log.d("DynamicLink", "DynamicLink$deepLink")
                    val postId = deepLink?.getQueryParameter("postId")
                    Log.d("PostIDD", "Post$postId")
                    val intent = Intent(this, DeepLinkingPostActivity::class.java)
                    intent.putExtra(DEEP_LINKING_POST_ID, postId)
                    startActivity(intent)
                }
               
            }
            .addOnFailureListener(this) { e ->   navigateWelcomeScreen() }
    }
```

then i am getting wrong value which i have set firebase console :

[image]

while i want get value of id can any one please help me how to get  deeplink id value which we have share so that based on id i can show particular data .

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have used the **"id"** parameter in the link you shared, but you are trying to get the **"postId"** parameter in your code. Therefore, you need to match the parameter names.

```
val postId = deepLink?.getQueryParameter("id")
```

Comment: but i am  not getting this link( https://xyz.page.link/navigator?id=6502ae981c4900015116c4fa) using intent you can see in URI we are getting different value which i have set in firebase dynamic link

Comment: Even if the link was correct, you would not be able to get the id value. This was the first thing that caught my attention.

Have you tested whether the value of `deepLink = pendingDynamicLinkData.link` is correct?
  Is there a problem when moving with 'Intent'? Or did you get the wrong link from the beginning?

Comment: my problem i am not getting correct link using  val uri = intent.data
i am expecting  https://xyz.page.link/navigator?id=6502ae981c4900015116c4fa but i am getting https://xyz.page.link/navigator which i have set dynamic link parameter in fire base  hope you understand